# Help with a revolution solid

Tags: geometry, 3d, volume, solid-of-revolution

Suppose I have an area in the cartesian system formed by the $y$ axis and a given function $y=f(x)$. How do I evaluate the volume of the solid formed by completely revolving this area around the $y$ axis (given a known interval $x\in[a,b]$)? Assuming that you can't invert the function to a form like $x=f(y)$. Thank you in advance.

Comment: It will depend on the function. You should be able to use shell method but whether you have to break your integral into multiple depends on the function and where it intercepts $x-$axis.

Comment: Bur what if I don't know the function? In my problem I am supposed to find it later minimizing a functional with other terms. I only know that $x\in[0,R]$, being $R$ a constant and $f'(x)>0 \forall x\in[0,R]$.

Comment: Take $x=f^{-1}(y)$ and swap the $x,y$ coordinates to $y=f^{-1}(x)$ if you prefer to think about horizontal solids of revolution.

Comment: Do you know $f(0)$ and $f(R)$? If not, assume $f(0) = a, f(R) = b$, $b \geq a$ and $a \geq b$ are two possibilities, then use the shell method to find volume of revolution.

Comment: No, I just know $f(R)=0$, but $f(0)<0$ since the function is crescent in the interval. I'll try to use the shell method then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in the Wikipedia [Solid of revolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_of_revolution#Cylinder_method) article, the volume of the solid formed by rotating the area between the $y$ axis and $y = f(x)$ and lines $x = a$ and $x = b$ is
$$V = 2 \pi \int_a^b x \lvert f(x) \rvert dx$$

For $f(x) \ge 0$, this is called [shell integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_integration),
$$V = 2 \pi \int_a^b x \; f(x) \; dx$$

Comment: I don't believe this is true, take for example the cone with radius $R$ and height $H$ formed by the revolution of the line $y=(H/R)x$: 
$$V=2\pi\int_{0}^{R}{x\left(\frac{H}{R}x\right)dx}=\frac{2}{3}\pi R^2H$$
Which is not the volume of the cone. I Believe this shell integration is used when you take the area between the $x$ axis and the function.

Comment: @MateusForcelini: that's an inverse cone.  That cone would be described by $y = H (R - x) / R$.

Comment: When you take the area between the $x$ axis and $y = f(x)$, the volume of the solid formed by rotating the area around the $x$ axis is $$V = \pi \int_a^b \Bigr( f(x) \Bigr)^2 \; dx$$This is called the disc method.  The one above is the cylinder method, which is equivalent to shell integration iff $f(x) \gt 0$.

Comment: Ok, but the volume of an inverse cone and a regular shouldn't be the same? It only changes the orientation

Comment: @MateusForcelini: No, the difference is a cylinder of radius $R$ and height $H$.  Your inverse cone is a cone subtracted from that cylinder.

Comment: Ok then. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @MateusForcelini integral for that cone will be $V=2\pi\int_{0}^{R}{x\left(H-\frac{H}{R}x\right)dx}$. The size of the shell at a given $x$ is different. The volume remains the same. Anyway this part is straightforward. The problem that you need to sort out is that your function may be such that $f(0) \ne 0$. So when you revolve you have a possibility that you have two different integrals to find volume.

Comment: @MateusForcelini: Math Lover is absolutely right, and the integral yields $V = \pi H R^2 / 3$.  If you can formulate $f(x)$ so that $f(x) \ge 0$ for $x \in [a, b]$, there is no problem.  Otherwise, you need to consider the regions where $f(x)$ is negative and where it is positive separately (and essentially integrate them piecewise).

Comment: Ok, so it comes from the module of the function, if my function is always either positive or negative I'll have only one integral, right?

Comment: @MateusForcelini: The integral you need to evaluate is $V = 2 \pi \int_a^b x \lvert f(x) \rvert dx$.  So yes, if $f(x)$ is nonpositive, or nonnegative, within the interval, you only need one integral.

Comment: If $f(0) \lt 0$ and it is monotonically increasing to $f(R) = 0$ then it is all good. Apply shell method - one integral.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much, guys. I applied at first but was struggling now to try to prove it for the volume of the cone and thought that maybe there was something wrong.